# How to get the attribute value of an xml code using linq

Tags: c#-4.0, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

```
<Shape ID="1" NameU="Start/End" Name="Start/End" Type="Shape" Master="2">
 ....</Shape>
<Shape ID="2" NameU="Start/End" Name="Start/End" Type="Shape" Master="5">
 ....</Shape>
```

I have to return the Master  value for every ID value.
How can i achieve it by using LINQ to XMl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't really present how your XML document looks like, so I assumed it's as follow:

```
<Shapes>
  <Shape ID="1" NameU="Start/End" Name="Start/End" Type="Shape" Master="2">
  </Shape>
  <Shape ID="2" NameU="Start/End" Name="Start/End" Type="Shape" Master="5">
  </Shape>
</Shapes>
```

You can simply get `Master` attribute value for all different `ID` like that:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load("Input.xml");

var masters = xDoc.Root
                  .Elements("Shape")
                  .ToDictionary(
                    x => (int)x.Attribute("ID"),
                    x => (int)x.Attribute("Master")
                  );
```

`masters` will be `Dictionary<int, int>` where key is your `ID` and value is corresponding `Master` attribute value.